# Chamar Funções no Python 3

Tags: python-3.x

Olá, estava "brincando" sem Python, e resolvi fazer um minijogo, para o PC jogar Jokempô comigo (SOU INICIANTE EM PROGRAMAÇÃO).

```
while pj <5 and pc <5:
def game()
```

Mas me deparei com o seguinte problema.

```
def game()
         ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Alguem pode me explicar onde errei?

Comment: A palavra chave `def` é utilizada para definir uma função, não chamá-la. Se deseja apenas invocar a função, utilize `game()`. Tome cuidado com a indentação do código.

Answer (score 1):

Os blocos de estruturas no python são feitos por identação. Portanto se você quer fazer um laço com a função game, deve identar 4 espaços antes da sua chamada.

```
while pj <5 and pc <5:
    game()
```

Também para a função **game()** funcionar, deve ser declarada antes da sua chamada.

```
def game():
    # instruções da função

# bloco do while
```